# jar file in Jboss for com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar

Tags: jboss, migration, websphere, sca

I am new to JBOSS and working on a project to migrate an application from WebSphere 7 to JBOSS EAP 6.3 but getting a compilation error in a java file implementing Spring FactoryBean importing "com.ibm.websphere.sca.ServiceManager" which is a class of ws.runtime-7.0.0.0.jar. Can anyone tell me what is a alternative jar I can use in JBOSS for this.

I have class which implements the Spring Frameworks FactoryBean interface so it can be used in the Spring configuration to create Service objects.It actually delegates to the WebSphere ServiceManager to create the service. 
I need to change this class or find an alternative way so that I can create service objects using JBOSS ServiceManager, below is the class which is used in WebSphere:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNameAware;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean;
import com.ibm.websphere.sca.ServiceManager;

public class ServiceFactoryBean implements FactoryBean, BeanNameAware {
private String beanName;
private Class<?> clazz;

/**
* Default constructor.
*/
public ServiceFactoryBean() {
super();
}

/*
* (non-Javadoc)
* @see      org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNameAware#setBeanName(java.lang.String)
*/
public void setBeanName(String beanName) {
this.beanName = beanName;
}

/**
* Sets the Class object for the service that is to be created.
* 
* @param clazz the Class of the service being created.
*/
public void setClass(Class<?> clazz) {
this.clazz = clazz;
}

/*
* (non-Javadoc)
* @see org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean#getObject()
*/
public Object getObject() throws Exception {
return ServiceManager.INSTANCE.locateService(this.beanName);
}

/*
* (non-Javadoc)
* @see org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean#getObjectType()
*/
public Class getObjectType() {
return this.clazz;
}

/*
* (non-Javadoc)
* @see org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean#isSingleton()
*/
public boolean isSingleton() {
return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Of course you are. (And why would you expect something that starts with "com.ibm" to be readily available in JBoss in the first place?) There's not enough information in your question to understand in what way your project depends on SCA - so it is hard to suggest the best strategy for the porting.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but as far as I know plain JBoss doesn't support SCA, so you either will have to stick with WebSphere, or make a major rewrite to your application as there is no easy replacement.

Comment: That is true JBOSS does not support SCA. So probably I need to rewrite this class. Another thing, the above code is a part of a common framework at Enterprise level so if any one wants to develop an application they can utilize common functionality implemented in this common framework like logging, exception handling, implementing factory pattern in there application. So if I might be able to write a implementation of Spring factory pattern without applicationContext.xml I think it will resolve the purpose. So can any one help me with that.